# Clear Room database on start in development environment

Tags: android, android-room

For development purpose, is there a way to automatically empty *all* Room data when I rebuild and restart the program? The way I can think of right now is to call some kind of `removeAll` at the start of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `RoomDatabase#clearAllTables();`

Sample usage:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    database.clearAllTables();
}
```